# Как задать путь для создания файла на сервере в WEB-INF?

Tags: spring-mvc, веб-сервер, файлы, java

Никак не получается создать файл в WEB-INF. Создается черти-где, не найти концов. На локальном TOMCAT создался в папке пользователя: где TOMCAT, a где пользователь. Уже 3 для мучаюсь, никак не могу сообразить, как путь указать. На настоящий сервер системщик раздеплоил и вообще не нашел, куда файл записался. :(  Помогите, кто знает. Пишу на java под Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@Helena2977](/users/24157/helena2977)](/users/24157/helena2977) если вам в любую папку относительно папки с tomcat, то можно записать так:

```
String fileName = directory + java.io.File.separator + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
java.io.File file = new java.io.File(fileName);
// утилита для записи 
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, multipartFile.getBytes());
```

где directory - это путь вида "`/%folder%/`".

В итоге получится (например): 
С:\tomcate
C:\file

Comment: Мне не на С: надо, а на сервере.  И вопрос как раз  в том, как задать это directory. И желательно не относительно tomcat, а относительно папки, куда деплоится приложение.

Comment: @Helena2977 посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529774/create-a-new-file-at-webcontent-or-web-inf-in-a-spring-mvc-application
`request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/");`

Comment: Путь правильный получился, папка создалась, как я и хотела, но файл в ней не создается почему-то. И никаких ошибок не выдается при этом.

Comment: @Helena2977 а файл в другую папку (не с севером) записывается нормально?

Comment: А нет, это я сама напутала. Спасибо большое. Все работает.

Answer (score 0):

С томкатом не работал, но видел похожую ситуацию с jboss. Сервер стартовали руками, а не как службу, и в зависимости, из какой папки вызывался скрипт и из подкакого пользователя, там и создовались системные файлы.

Мой совет: смотрите системные переменные запущенного сервера, он должен показать, куда заливает файлы.

Comment: А нельзя как-то задать этот путь, чтобы внутри своей папки было? Мне все равно, внутри какой, но своей. Есть же папка, где WEB-INF и классы лежат. Можно туда, или прямо в WEB-INF.